# Why doesn't regex replace my content with my DateTime? C#

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

I'm trying to replace a line in my text file just like I did when I replaced, --- INSERT GROUP HERE --- , but when I attempt to replace the line with the due date, It doesn't replace it at all!

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dueDate = today.AddDays(7);
string htmlDueDate = Regex.Replace(emailFormat, "INSERT DUE DATE", dueDate.ToString());
string htmlLines = Regex.Replace(emailFormat, "--- INSERT GROUP HERE ---", teamSplit[0]);
```

So at least I know that I can implement a successful Regex.replace when I replace the, `--- INSERT GROUP HERE ---`, line.

I've tested the output with `WriteLine`, and can see the whole date with time included, how can I include only the month and day?

Comment: You're using `emailFormat` in both Regex methods. You probably meant to use a different pattern for the date.

Comment: Show us emailFormat.

Comment: Why `Regex.Replace` instead of `String.Replace`? You're not doing regular expressions, or didn't show that part.

Comment: All I'm saying is that I'm able to run the program and the program does replace the string using Regex for htmlLines, but it doesn't replace it at all for htmlDueDate. This is not the first time I use a regex expression to change a string in my text file, but why isn't it working exclusively for this case? What good is it to show you the text file with the string I want to replace when it's clearly altering all the other values using regex? I know how to use regex

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like 
dueDate.ToString("ddMM")

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to replace "INSERT DUE DATE" in the email format string with simply month and day.

You could do this:

```
dueDate.ToString("MMDD");
```

There are other options depending on how you want to format the month and day. I always reference this page for number formatting: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: I'm asking why am I able to change htmlLines with regex but not htmlDueDate. I've used regex throughout my program succesfuly. It's not working on this instance. Yes, I want to do that, using the code but it's not doing it.